# Login with Facebook sends to Google login

Tags: bug, status-completed, login

I've tried to login with Facebook, just after trying to upvote a question without being logged in. When I clicked Login with Facebook (triple checked, tried again and again), I was redirected to login with Google page. Login with Facebook button acts the same as Login with Google button. I managed to login with clicking Login With StackExchange, and from there, Login with Facebook, sucessfully though.

Comment: indeed, same happens to me here

Comment: Obviously, Google bought Facebook

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing it. Working it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oof, good find. I have patched this up and we'll be doing a prod build ASAP to push the fix out. Thanks for identifying this!